# nginx-ingress-controller: Error while initializing connection to Kubernetes apiserver

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

nginx-ingress-controller error. it gives error while initializing connection to kubernetes apiserver. Is there some issue with the cluster, not able to understand this issue. I want to expose my services outside cluster. below is the docker logs with the error and my nginx-ingress-controller.yml

docker log

```
Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
F1128 06:30:25.376076       7 launch.go:330] Error while initializing connection to 
Kubernetes apiserver. This most likely means that the cluster is misconfigured (e.g., it has 
invalid apiserver certificates or service accounts configuration). Reason: Get  
https://10.96.0.1:443/version: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
```

nginx-controller.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx


--- 
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
labels:
  app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
type: LoadBalancer
selector:
app: ingress-nginx
ports:
- name: http
port: 80
targetPort: http
- name: https
port: 443
targetPort: https


---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: nginx-ingress-controller
namespace: default
spec:
replicas: 1
#  selector:
#    matchLabels:
#      app: ingress-nginx
template:
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/port: '10254'
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-ingress-controller
      image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.17
          args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend-external

        - --logtostderr
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-config
        - --default-ssl-certificate=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-tls
      env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
      ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
         containerPort: 443
```

what could be the reason

Comment: In your kind Deployment try "apps/v1" in apiVersion and try again.

Comment: getting same error

Comment: Check your kubernetes deployment. Is it properly running? Check that from the dashboard.

Comment: Did you run the default backend pod/service nginx-default-backend-external pod? Can you confirm that pod is running without issue?

Comment: @PrithviSingh I didn't had dashboard configured, so now when i'm doing it, I'm getting the similar error for dashboard too .

Comment: @AlirezaDavid Also  checked the default backend pods, the docker is in up state but the command is /pause if I do docker ps -a . there is some mess I guess trying to figure it out

Comment: I'd like to reproduce your issue. Please correct your `Service` and `Deployment` yaml. Your cluster is bare-mateal or On-Prem? Whats env (linux, windows) and what version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: I'm using the yml this one as it is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml have just commented out livenessProbe , readinessProbe and nodeSelector sections otherwise everything is same . still getiing the same error

Comment: Please specify your environment. Its On-Prem or local like minikube or kubeadm? It was deployed on new cluster or you did on it some deploys earlier? Also what version of K8s are you using?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS , the issue got resolved. My Cluster was broken, below are the  mistakes which I was doing . 1. I was using wrong `cidr` in `--pod-network-cidr` arg. I was using the same network cidr as my hosts, it should have been around this series `10.244.0.0/16` . 2. As we do the initialization of Kubernetes, the CoreDNS crashes. so to resolve it I was commenting the loop in this `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns` where as I just had to install flannel and delete the coredns pods so that it could take the changes . It worked fine as I resolved these issues .

Comment: @Charvee Punia Could you write root cause of your issue with solution as an answer? It will be more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as Community Wiki based on comments, for better visibility.

Root cause of issue was **not with `nginx-controller`** settings but with `Kubernetes Cluster Configuration`.

**1. Using wrong `cidr`.**

Original Poster used same value of `--pod-network-cidr` as host. It is described in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network).

> Also, beware, that your Pod network must not overlap with any of the host networks as this can cause issues. If you find a collision between your network plugin’s preferred Pod network and some of your host networks, you should think of a suitable CIDR replacement and use that during kubeadm init with --pod-network-cidr and as a replacement in your network plugin’s YAML.

**2. [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/#about-coredns) crash.**

Original Poster changied `ConfigMap` using `kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns` which contains information about `CoreDNS` configuration (commented loop). Later OP installed `CNI` - Flannel and restarted `CoreDNS` pods to receive new configuration from `ConfigMap`.

After that `Nginx-controller` configuration YAMLs worked fine.